Mongo Aggregation Query Slowness
I’m facing some query slowness issue in my complex set of query stages with the million dump of records.
Can any one share me the some point of thoughts, it might be helpful for me to end this process.
db.getCollection("states").aggregate([
    { "$project": { "_id": 1 } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "allbama",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } },
            ],
            "as": "allbama"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": " alaska",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": " alaska"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": " arizona",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": " arizona"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "california",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "california"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "colorado",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "colorado"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "florida",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "florida"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "lowa",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "lowa"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "maine",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "maine"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "nevada",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "nevada"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "oregon",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "oregon"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "texas",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "texas"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "utah",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "utah"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "vermont",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "vermont"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "virginia",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "virginia"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "washington",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "state",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
                            "$lte": ISODate("2024-01-31T18:30:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "flag": "Security Flag"
                    }
                },
                { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
            ],
            "as": "washington"
        }
    },
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "hasSecurityFlag": {
                    "$or": [
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$allbama" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$ alaska" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$ arizona" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$california" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$colorado" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$florida" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$lowa" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$maine" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$nevada" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$oregon" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$texas" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$utah" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$vermont" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$virginia" }, 0] },
                        { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$washington" }, 0] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "hasSecurityFlag": true
            }
        },
        
]);

In this Query, I can able to get the results in below 5 seconds from lots of huge records without using the final match stage {"$match": {"hasSecurityFlag": true}}, But when I add this match stage it takes 3 to 4 minutes for the results.
But this is not an default collection field. So i can’t able to add appropriate index for this match stage. What can be updated to get this query process optimized and efficient.
I need to get the query result in few seconds and need to resolve any index issues.

Have you run that query using explain with the executionStats option?

If I am not mistaken, your aggregation pipeline has 15(!) $lookup. Certainly you have a bad database design. MongoDB ist not a relational database, it is not optimized for joins. Review your data model and reduce the number of collections.

the first state { "$project": { "_id": 1 } } will make a collection scan

Thanks all and In this case i will able to get the results within 5 seconds without using the final match stage {"$match": {"hasSecurityFlag": true}}, it may be any reason the query stucks with the final match stage?

I couldn't agree more with @Wernfried Domscheit that your schema probably needs to be reconsidered. It is not obvious to me at all why you have this information spread across different collections. Perhaps you can keep it all in the same collection and add a state field to the documents instead of implicitly capturing that information in the collection names (and vastly complicating your queries).
I'll attempt to answer your question about why the presence of the final $match stage appears to drastically influence overall execution time and provide some suggestion(s) about how to improve the operation as-is.

Why the slowness with the trailing $match?
In short, your comparison is not necessarily 'apples to apples' as they say. Specifically when you note that you are "able to get the results in below 5 seconds from lots of huge records without using the final match" you haven't clarified if this is all of the results or if it is instead just the first batch of results.
We don't have enough information to say for certain, but what's probably happening here is that the trailing $match is forcing your aggregation stage to process further along than when it is run without it. Without it, the database is going to feed back the first batch of results as soon as it is ready without having to discard any results. But with the $match it now has to throw out results that don't match which delays the generation of the first batch. If you were to force the full execution of the aggregation pipeline without the $match, eg by appending .itcount() or appending a {$count: "total"} stage to the end of the pipeline, I suspect that you would see similar slowness.
Having additional information such as how many documents are in this source states collection and what do they look like would be very helpful in allowing us to better understand the problem.

What can you do to improve performance [without changing the schema]?
Again we don't have enough information to say with certainty what is causing all of the slowness, so a bit of the suggestions here are speculative.
Add Indexes
By far the most important and obvious thing to do would be to make sure that the collections have the appropriate indexes. So for each of the collections you are calling $lookup against, you'll want to have an index on { state: 1, flag: 1, createdAt: 1, _id: 1}. The _id part is optional but would allow each of these operations to have the additional covering optimization.
Potentially add $limit to the $lookup pipelines
It's not clear what the desired business logic for this pipeline is. But if "all" that you are looking for are states that have one or more security flags during the specified timeline, then you could add a { $limit: 1 } stage to each of the pipelines in all of the $lookups. It could be written before or after the $project. This would allow the database to stop its work for a state as soon as the first one was identified.
Obviously you cannot use this approach if you want the full list of matching entries for the states.
Use $unionWith instead
I don't see a particularly compelling reason to use a bunch of $lookups here. Instead of grabbing all of the documents from the states collection to start (or similarly using $documents to list out the values of interest), you could instead convert all (but the first) of the $lookups into $unionWiths stages. Whether or not this is valuable and what the definition of those pipelines are depends again on the specific logic that you are trying to achieve.

By the way, you have a typo in allbama.

Thanks and Greatful , you learned me a lot.
I will make the updates as per your suggestions and keep on share my point of views.
